# testing input events with react testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

I've created a small keypad app in react and I'm trying to test the input event on the app and for some reason I am not getting the expected result. I'm trying to test it to failure and success. The test I'm running is this below, I want to input `1995` (the correct combination), click the unlock button and ultimately have a message return `Unlocked!` but it only returns `Incorrect Code!` which should only happen if the code is incorrect or the input field is empty. But it shouldn't be empty as I have filled it out in the test..

here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cloud-gywu6?file=/src/App.test.js:0-26

Any ideas?

test:

```
const setup = () => {
  const utils = render(<App />);
  const input = utils.getByLabelText("input-code");
  return {
    input,
    ...utils
  };
};

test("It should return a successful try", async () => {
  const { input, getByTestId } = setup();
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "1995" } });
  });
  expect(input.value).toBe("1995");

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId("unlockbutton"));
  });
  expect(getByTestId("status")).toHaveTextContent("Unlocked!");
});
```

the component I'm trying to test

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Keypad from "./components/Keypad";

import "./App.css";
import "./css/Result.css";

function App() {
  //correctCombination: 1995

  const [result, setResult] = useState("");
  const [locked, setLocked] = useState("Locked");
  const [tries, setTries] = useState(0);
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(true);

  //Along with the maxLength property on the input,
  // this is also needed for the keypad
  useEffect(() => {
    (function() {
      if (result >= 4) {
        setResult(result.slice(0, 4));
      }
    })();
  }, [result]);

  const onClick = button => {
    switch (button) {
      case "unlock":
        checkCode();
        break;
      case "clear":
        clear();
        break;
      case "backspace":
        backspace();
        break;
      default:
        setResult(result + button);
        break;
    }
  };

  const checkCode = () => {
    if (result === "1995") {
      setLocked("Unlocked!");
      setTries(0);
    } else if (tries === 3) {
      setHide(false);
      setLocked("Too many incorrect attempts!");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setHide(true);
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      setLocked("Incorrect code!");
      setTries(tries + 1);
    }
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setResult("");
  };

  const backspace = () => {
    setResult(result.slice(0, -1));
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    setResult(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="pin-body">
        <h1>Pin Pad</h1>
        <div className="status">
          <h2 data-testid="status">{locked}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="result">
          <input
            maxLength={4}
            type="phone"
            aria-label="input-code"
            data-testid="inputcode"
            placeholder="Enter code"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={result}
          />
        </div>
        {hide ? <Keypad onClick={onClick} /> : false}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you reproduce in a codesandbox ?

Comment: aquinq here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cloud-gywu6?file=/src/App.test.js:0-26

Comment: `Keypad.js` is empty apparently

Comment: Yeah my fault, I forgot to save it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that were causing it to fail:

- Your input field is initially hidden, so you need to wait for it to appear using a findBy* query.
- You don't need to wrap `fireEvent` with `act`, because it already handles this for you.

A few stylistic notes:

- You should use `screen` instead of destructuring the result of render.
- You should `render` in the test.  Using test utilities to share rendering is an anti-pattern because it makes your test tougher to maintain individually and tougher to understand since it doesn't encapsulate all of the configuration under test.

Definitely take a look at [Common Mistakes with React Testing Library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library).  It will clear up some of the mystery and solidify some good patterns.

This test passes:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import React from "react";
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("It should return a successful try", async () => {
  render(<App />);
  const input = await screen.findByLabelText("input-code");

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "1995" } });
  expect(input.value).toBe("1995");

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("unlockbutton"));
  expect(screen.getByText("Unlocked!")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Fixed your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-torvalds-f2x39h?file=/src/App.test.js)